# SEO on external html page renderd by <object> tag

Tags: seo, external, google-search, html-object

I have this HTML:

```html
<body>
  <object id="post" data="post/Requirement Process Narative.html" type="text/html"> </object>
</body>
```

I want Google to index the keywords from the file `Requirement Process Narative.html` also.

That is if `Requirement Process Narative.html` contains "Domain Knowledge Acquiring" and someone searches for "Domain Knowledge Acquiring", Google will display the current page in its search list.

How to do it?

Comment: Do you want to know if Google indexes it, or do you know that Google doesn’t index it and you look for an alternative?

Comment: what test have you run to confirm the content wont be index'd?

Answer (score 1):

Google gets and indexed object tags, if they are matching Schema.org standards.
So your content has the potential to be interpreted and included in the SERP if useful for the end user.

You can read more about Schema here:
http://blog.schema.org/2011/07/on-june-2-nd-we-announced-collaboration.html

Consider also to use Google Web Master, [Fetch as Google Bot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066467?hl=en) feature to see what actually Google see of your page and for optimize your code.